# KQL query for managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, kql

I'm quite new to KQL , however it appears to be the best way to do what i want which is I'm using the Highlighted Content webpart and wish to display documents from another site which are tagged with one or more managed metadata columns.

For example, on Site A i wish to display documents from Site B which are tagged with Term set (Office) = Term (London).

What would the query be? Currently mine is the following however it's not working:

ows_taxId_Office:"GP0|#7ee8fd39-392c-4d6e-a05b-e4903122ab25"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the managed property in the KQL section.
For example, I have a metadata column named **Metadata**, and the managed property name for the corresponding crawled property is **owstaxIdMetadata**.

[image]

So the [KQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) I use to display the documents filled with term "Sales & Marketing" is (Double quotes can be omitted):

```
ContentType:Document owstaxIdMetadata:"94710101-4b23-408f-8c6b-f3ae0443cb45"
```

Or

```
ContentType:Document owstaxIdMetadata:Sales & Marketing
```

And in your scenario it should be:

```
owstaxIdOffice:"7ee8fd39-392c-4d6e-a05b-e4903122ab25"
```